# BI multi-dimensional modeling: How to turn measures into dimensions?

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, dimensional-modeling

so here´s what i plan to do: Let´s say we have a typical sales fact table with typical columns like:

```
Date, SalesRep, Product, Region, Units, Amount
```

Now, simple enough, I can sum over the Amount and roll it up against the Region like this:

```
Region      Sum of Revenue
------      --------------
North       56,234 $
South       48,788 $
East        38,787 $
West        15,334 $
```

But what if I want to have it another way, like this:

```
Revenue range    Region
-------------    ------
>50,000          North
>25,000          South
                 East
>10,000          West
```

That would mean to treat quantitative facts as a dimension and vice versa, right? But how can i transform measures into dimensions?

Any push into the right direction would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Dynamic value banding:

http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/dynamic-value-banding/

> A dynamic value banding report is organized as a series of report row
> headers that deﬁne a progressive set of varying-sized ranges of a
> target numeric fact. For instance, a common value banding report in a
> bank has many rows with labels such as “Balance from 0 to $10,”
> “Balance from $10.01 to $25,” and so on.
>
> This kind of report is
> dynamic because the speciﬁc row headers are deﬁned at query time, not
> during the ETL processing. The row deﬁnitions can be implemented in a
> small value banding dimension table that is joined via
> greater-than/less-than joins to the fact table, or the deﬁnitions can
> exist only in an SQL CASE statement.
>
> The value banding dimension
> approach is probably higher performing, especially in a columnar
> database, because the CASE statement approach involves an almost
> unconstrained relation scan of the fact table.

### Banding dimension table:

```
ID | RANGE_SET    | RANGE_NAME | RANGE_MIN    | RANGE_MAX
---|--------------|------------|--------------|---------------
1  | THREE_RANGES | >50,000    |  50,000.01 $ | 9,999,999.00 $
2  | THREE_RANGES | >25,000    |  25,000.01 $ |    50,000.00 $
3  | THREE_RANGES | >10,000    |  10,000.01 $ |    25,000.00 $
10 | BIG_SMALL    | Small      |       0.00 $ |   100,000.00 $
11 | BIG_SMALL    | Big        | 100.000.01 $ | 9,999,999.00 $
```

The column `RANGE_SET` allows to store a few sets of ranges in the same dimension table and is used to group the defined ranges.

### Aggregated fact table:

If you are dealing with a **large fact table** and the dynamic approach is too resource intensive, you can load data into an **aggregated fact table** and use the sum of revenue to fetch an appropriate banding key.

```
REGION | BANDING_ID | SUM_OF_REVENUE
-------|------------|---------------
North  | 1          |       56,234 $
South  | 2          |       48,788 $
East   | 2          |       38,787 $
West   | 3          |       15,334 $
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Marek. The example i chose was quite poor, actually i don´t want to assign _aggregated_ values to those banded dimension but _row level_ facts. So, to stick to the example, i want to assign the single amounts to staggered ranges.

Comment: @Prefect73 I'm not sure if I follow. Do you want to assign every fact row (that contains revenue value) to one of the ranges defined in a banding dimension? You can do that using the above approach, but the classification stops being valid once you group the rows by region and roll up multiple rows, e.g. adding two `>10,000` rows can produce one that falls into the same range (11,000 $ + 12,000 $) or a `>25,000` one (15,000 $ + 16,000 $) - you need to calculate the sum and assign the range dynamically. Let me know if I am on the right track here.

Comment: but since this was the right answer to the wrong question i mark it of course :)